# Rails 4.0 - wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) - for a nested 'IF' statement in a View

Tags: if-statement, view, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting a `ArgumentError in Members#index` of `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` at the line `<% if m.platforms %>` in the following code. What extra argument do I have here? I don't know why I'm getting this error and searching on SO and Google hasn't given me an answer for this specific situation.

I have a rails 4.0 view that uses the following *(simplified for readability)*:

**View:**

```
<% if @members %>
    <% for m in @members %>
        <% if m.platforms %>
            <% for p in m.platforms %>
                <%= link_to p.name, :controller => 'members', :action => 'platforms', :id => p.id %>
            <% end %>
        <% else %>
            do something else...
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% else %>
    ...
```

**Controller:**

```
def index
    if current_user
        @members = current_user.members
    end
end
```

Comment: Did you copy paste you code correctly? You do not have `end` for the second iteration `<% for p in m.platforms %>`

Comment: Yeah, I accidentally removed that when I was stripping out all of the HTML. I'll update.

Comment: 1. try to use another way for iteration `@members.each do |m|` 2. maybe your method `m.platforms` requires some parameters?! - check it in your console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So terrible answer, but somehow it just kinda fixed itself. I hate when that happens... I would've rather know exactly what I did to get it working... I made a bunch of changes to the models that this view uses, so it was probably related to that.. Wish I could help the next person that comes across this. If you stumble across this and are having the same problem, please comment below and I will try to help, then update this answer with the correct one once we know what happened. Sorry google users...

Answer (score 0):

You missed the "do" in your "for m in @members" and "for p in m.platforms"..

```
<% if @members %>
  <% for m in @members do %> # add the "do"
    <% if m.platforms %>
      <% for p in m.platforms do %> # add the "do"
        <%= link_to p.name, :controller => 'members', :action => 'platforms', :id => p.id %>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      do something else...
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
 do something else...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I added the do in both places, and I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: Can you post your controller action pls?

Comment: Not much to it, but there you go, do you need the model? it is a `has_many through` many-to-many relationship between `Member` and `Platform`

Comment: I could not see any more errors :). Maybe you have to open a console and try out the loops and get more information where the error could be..